# IE not reading CSS properly, putting content beneath sidebar

Tags: css, internet-explorer

I am trying to correct CSS to make it compatible with IE. My page looks fine in chrome and Firefox. I want to put a text box beside my navigation that's on the left, but instead IE displays the text box beneath everything else.

Check out [bcaplan.com](http://bcaplan.com) to see my problem.

Comment: I dont see a text box anywhere on that website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `margin-left: 190px;` on `#rcol` with `float: right;`